# Is the column space of B always contained in the column space of AB?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is the column space of $B$ always contained in the column space of $AB$ where $B$ and $AB$ are two matrices? I do not think that this is the case, so, I am trying to find a counterexample. So, far, I think that if I take the column space of $A$ to be the zero subspace, then the column space of $AB$ would also be zero subspace. Then, I can take the column space of $B$ to be anything other than the zero subspace which is where I run into trouble. How can I write this out with proper notation? Can someone please suggest a concrete example for $col(B)$? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Let $A=\pmatrix{0&&0\\0&&0}$ and $B=\pmatrix{1&&1\\2&&2}$. Then $AB=A$,

and the column space of $B$ is spanned by $\pmatrix{1\\2}$,

which is not in the column space of $A$, which is only $\pmatrix{0\\0}$.